# how to find only folders greater than 100MB or 1G in linux

Tags: shell, unix

I have actually tried few commands from couple of blogs but it does not seems to work properly. In the below case I mentioned to find folders raning from 500M to 1000MB but, it displays lower size folders as well.

https://www.unixtutorial.org/2014/07/how-to-find-directories-larger-than-1gb-in-linux/

```
global1:/u01/app/oowner/diag/rdbms> du -h --max-depth=1 /u01/app/oowner/diag/rdbms  | grep '[500-1000]M\>' | sort -r
975M    /u01/app/oowner/diag/rdbms/uscs01
7.5M    /u01/app/oowner/diag/rdbms/qscs8
615M    /u01/app/oowner/diag/rdbms/tscss11
45M     /u01/app/oowner/diag/rdbms/cst01c1
41M     /u01/app/oowner/diag/rdbms/cst01
3.1M    /u01/app/oowner/diag/rdbms/tscss12
```

Would really appreciate your help on with this commands.

Thanks
Mohammeddba.

Comment: A solution with `awk`: `du -m --max-depth=1 /u01/app/oowner/diag/rdbms |awk '$1>500 {print}'`

Comment: @Mohammeddba : Your `grep` command selects those lines, where one of the digits 0 or 1 or 5 is followed by the letter M. It would not select, for instance, an entry having 642M.

Comment: or maybe just remove the "human" `-h` flag from `du` and then sort the results numerically `| sort -nr`. Keep it simple.

Comment: The linked tutorial is not just bad practice, most of it doesn't even work.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` does not work that way. It uses character ranges not number ranges.

For example `[a-c]` matches `a` or `b` or `c`.
When not using `-` any of the characters is matched `[abc]` also matches `a` or `b` or `c`.

Therefor `[0-1]` matches `0` or `1`.

And `[500-1000]` matches `5` or `0` or `0` or `1` or `0` or `0` or `0`.
It is the same as `[015]`

Finally a match is found anywhere in the searched lines, so for example `[015]M` also matches a line with `7777775M`.

The solusion to match 500 - 999 would be:

`^[5-9]\?[0-9]\?[0-9](\.[0-9]*)\?M`

To match 500 - 1000 it would get a little more complicated:

`^\([5-9]\|10\)\?[0-9]\?[0-9](\.[0-9]*)\?M`

---

I suggest not using regular expressions to parse a number range.

You can use `awk` or even a shell loop if you want to keep using some grep. awk is much faster, a shell loop would look something like this:

```
du -h --max-depth=1 /u01/app/oowner/diag/rdbms | grep '^[0-9\.]*M' | while read -r line; do
    num=$(echo "$line" | grep -o '^[0-9]*')
    if test "$num" -ge 500; then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done | sort -rh
```

`awk` was mentioned by @PackardCPW's comment on the question

Comment: Thank you so much. Really appreciate your help on this.